# characters in fb apps/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, character-encoding

I'm getting � this character in my facebook app instead of "£"- I checked the mysql db and the character is being stored as £. How do i fix this? This has never happened to me before - I'm using PHP as well.

Comment: Is your database encoding set to utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `mb_convert_encoding()` to convert the character from whatever character set it's being stored in, to the character set Facebook is being displayed in.

eg:

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')
```

See: http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding for more information.

Comment: thanks- i wrote this into a function called cs- convert string as typing out that function and the parameters is very laboriuos

function cs($item)
{

 $item = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
 
 return $item;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
> &pound;
```

You need the Character code. Or use UTF-8 Encoding. http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding.en.php

Or use the (`mb_convert_encoding()`) function in PHP as PGL states.